# Last Update CM13 - Nexus 5X

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-update

Yesterday I updated from this snapshot version **2016-04-18 17:30:08** to the last one **2016-08-20 00:21:07** (bullhead)

Everything looks in its place, but yesterday the device was keeping restarting, today it's stable.
I tried to reboot it by myself and when boot it says:

**There’s an internal problem with your device. Contact your manufacturer for details.**

Any solution?

Comment: So, did you try to contact the manufacturer? And CM updater uses recovery to flash the zip so...

Comment: Well, true.. it's the same thing. Btw no, I can't contact the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a soulution [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-9/development/fix-build-prop-variety-fix-aka-contact-t3133347) but it's for Nexus 6P and Android 5.1 but I think it will work in your case as well.

> **Android System**
>
> There's an internal problem with your device. Contact your manufacturer for details.

The problem occurs because of a check that Google implemented in Android 5.1 (and it seems stayed in after) which compares `/system/build.prop` with the values found in `/vendor/build.prop`.

If they differ you get that error message. All one has to do to get rid of the error is to change the **3 values** in `/vendor/build.prop` according to the values in `/system/build.prop`.

On the link you can find a flashable zip. The magic is in the `update-binary` file:

```
/sbin/busybox egrep "^ro\.build\.(date(\.utc)?|fingerprint)=" /system/build.prop \
    | /sbin/busybox sed -e"s/^ro\./ro.vendor./" \
    > /vendor/build.prop
```

So you need:

- install `TWRP` on your device
- send `vendor-build-prop-fix-signed.zip` to your device
- `reboot` into `recovery mode`
- flash the zip but **don't wipe anything**
- reboot your phone

If it's not work (but it should be work), you can try [this method](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-5x/help/theres-internal-problem-device-t3308647).

It says you should download and flash/install the `vendor.img` which matches your ROM's base.

Comment: The last sentence is the one on point. Update the vendor image and ignore the warning. CM uses a single branch for all devices so even when on the latest vendor image the warning will still pop up.